# using gdb to debug , the tracepoint is not the same with the line number of code

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

first of all, the optimization level is -O0, and include -ggdb3 flag
when I use gdb to debug, the tracepoint is not consistent with the line number which I use "list" to get, it always over a few lines; the cpp has over 10000 lines, whether is it because the file is so large that make gdb be wrong in line number.
for example, the tracepoint of gdb is 1005 line, but actually it is only on 1000 line.

Comment: @lee, when u compile a debug version even it will removed all white spaces (your formatting), so, of course, it is not all same. It will contain only real code lines.

Comment: @Шах，I think it is not the reason, there are many white spaces, but the tracepoint is only over a few lines

Comment: @lee, okay, when post all compilation flags. U need to set debug flag in other case it will not save additional information to your debugger can link it with a source code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here's a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417880/why-does-my-debugger-sometimes-freak-out-and-do-things-like-not-line-up-with-my) that largely answers yours.
2. In addition, do you include the -g to include debug information.

Comment: I have included -ggdb3 flag to include debug information

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason, the cpp file is upload from windows, this format of file is DOS, every line has a "line feed", so the gdb get wrong info.
change the format of file from dos to uinx is OK!